# Python: Fitting a 3D function using MLPRegressor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, regression

I'm trying to use an MLPRegressor to fit a predefined 3D function. The problem is that I can't get to print the correct result and therefore my fitting looks awful when plotted.

The function it the following:

```
def threeDFunc(xin,yin):
    z = np.zeros((40,40))
    for xIndex in range(0,40,1):
        for yIndex in range(0,40,1):
            z[xIndex,yIndex]=(np.exp(-(xin[xIndex]**2+yin[yIndex]**2)/0.1))
    return z



xThD = np.arange(-1,1,0.05)
yThD = np.arange(-1,1,0.05)
zThD = threeDFunc(xThD, yThD)
```

[image: 3Dplot]

The above plot is what it should approximate.

[image: 3Dplot with approximation]

The red is what it does.

The code looks like this:

```
classifier = neural_network.MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(200, 200), activation='logistic', learning_rate='adaptive')

xy = np.array((xThD.flatten(),yThD.flatten()))

classifier.fit(np.transpose(xy), zThD)

pre = classifier.predict(np.transpose(xy))

import pylab
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xThD, yThD)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, zThD)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, pre, color='red')
print(np.shape(zThD))
print(np.shape(pre))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the activation function to the hyperbolic tan function with `activation='tanh'` and the solver to lbfgs with `solver='lbfgs'`.

If your classifier instantiation then looks as follows, the plots of red and blue should be nearly identical:

```
classifier = neural_network.MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(200, 200), solver='lbfgs', activation='tanh', learning_rate='adaptive')
```